cookies _clsk & _clck are not set as SameSite=None;Secure. Clarity implementation using GTM
I have implemented microsoft clarity using Google Tag Manager and currently I am not able to set the cookies as SameSite=None;Secure. I do not have any option in the clarity and google tag manager consoles.
How can I implement the cookies with SameSite=None and Secure?
I could set the cookies dynamically in my js but this might affect the clarity's analysis and tracking. I'd prefer if I could set it in console or by some other way that doesn't involve manually manipulating the cookie.
